# Align figures in beamer

Tags: beamer, floats

I would like to include three figures in a beamer slide. I should have one figure on the top and two at the bottom. I tried to do that with minipage but it does not show the desired result. I guess I am messing up with the dimension of the figures. My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,t,11pt]{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
\framesubtitle{Example1}
\begin {figure}
\vspace{-2.5ex}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=3.5 cm,height=2.5 cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{First}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\pause[2]
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textheight}
\includegraphics[width=3.5 cm,height=2.5 cm]{example-image-b}
\caption{Second}
\end{minipage}
\pause[3]
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textheight}
\includegraphics[width=3.5 cm,height=2.5 cm]{example-image-c}
\caption{Third}
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Do you have any hint to share? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the surrounding `minipage` for the last two, but add a `%` at the end of a couple of the lines there to avoid a space between the two on the second line. Alternatively, you could make them a bit narrower than half the `\textwidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[t,11pt]{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
\framesubtitle{Example1}
\begin {figure}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3.5 cm,height=2.5 cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{First}
\end{minipage}
\pause[2]
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3.5 cm,height=2.5 cm]{example-image-b}
\caption{Second}
\end{minipage}%
\pause[3]%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3.5 cm,height=2.5 cm]{example-image-c}
\caption{Third}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
\framesubtitle{Example1}
\begin {figure}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3.5 cm,height=2.5 cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{First}
\end{minipage}
\pause[2]
% an empty line here, i.e. a paragraph break, ensures that the next minipage ends up on the next line.    

\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3.5 cm,height=2.5 cm]{example-image-b}
\caption{Second}
\end{minipage}
\pause[3]
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3.5 cm,height=2.5 cm]{example-image-c}
\caption{Third}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another approach could be using beamers `columns` environment to place the figures besides each other.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,t,11pt]{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
\framesubtitle{Example1}
\begin{figure}  
    \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{First}
\end{figure}
\pause
\vskip-2\baselineskip
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth, T]
    \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{example-image-b}
            \caption{Second}
        \end{figure}
    \end{column}
    \pause
    \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{example-image-c}
            \caption{Third}
        \end{figure}
    \end{column}    
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]